# When adding divs elements to my page all the other draggable items move?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does this keep happening?

I add a draggable element, move it into place and then it prepends and moves everything down or make the page huge? Is there a way I can make the div appear in the same place and not move the other elements on the page? This is driving me crazy!

---

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>draggable demo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h2></h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
        <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    </form>
    <div id="button">Add!</div>
    <br/>
<table><tr><td id="place"></td></tr></table>

 </body>
</html>
```

---

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
 //$( '#draggable' ).draggable();
 $('#button').click(function()
 {
     var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
     var $newdiv = "<div id='draggable'>" + toAdd + "</div>";
     //$("#place").html($($newdiv).draggable());

     $("#place").prepend($($newdiv).draggable());
 });

});
```

---

**CSS:**

```
#draggable {
 z-index:1;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #ccc;
}

h2 {
 font-family:arial;
}

form {
 display: inline-block;
}

#button{
 display:inline-block;
 height:20px;
 width:70px;
 background-color:#cc0000;
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:2px;
}

#item {
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#000000;
 width:90%;
 height:800px;
 background-color:#cc0000;
}

#place {
 z-index:1;
 font-family:garamond;
 color:#000;
 width:800px;
 height:800px;
 background-color:#f00;
}
```

Cheers in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fully working code: jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ycgmt/

**Changes:**

1: <div> instead of <table>

2: append() instead of prepend()

3: class instead of id

4: position:absolute

---

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>draggable demo</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h2></h2>
    <form name="checkListForm">
        <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
    </form>
    <div id="button">Add!</div>
    <br/>

    <div id="place"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.draggable {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background: #ccc;
     position:absolute;
}

h2 {
    font-family:arial;
}

form {
    display: inline-block;
}

#button{
     display:inline-block;
     height:20px;
     width:70px;
     background-color:#cc0000;
     font-family:arial;
     font-weight:bold;
     color:#ffffff;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align:center;
     margin-top:2px;
}

#item {
     font-family:garamond;
     color:#000000;
     width:90%;
     height:800px;
     background-color:#cc0000;
}

#place {
     z-index:1;
     font-family:garamond;
     color:#000;
     width:800px;
     height:800px;
     background-color:#f00;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     $('#button').click(function()
     {
         var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
         var newdiv = $("<div class='draggable'>" + toAdd + "</div>");

         $("#place").append(newdiv);

         $(newdiv).draggable();
     });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works at placing the new code at the same point but it moves the previous div by the 100px I set as the width

Comment: Do you want the divs on top of each other?

Comment: Yeah but cant seem to get the css to work positioning to work on the new elements as they are draggable

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle.net sample for your problem?